# Characterizing delta neighborhoods of a complex derivative

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a complex derivative $f'(z)$ as the limit of the difference quotient, such that $|h|<\delta \implies |\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}-f'(z)|<\epsilon$, where $\delta>0$ results from choosing $\epsilon>0$, as usual. Suppose there is a bounded region where $f(z)$ is uniformly continuous but $f'(z)$ is not proven to be continuous (bear with me).

Having found some $\delta$ that works for a particular $z$ and $\epsilon$, can we conclude anything about $\delta$ for nearby $z$, or for slightly smaller $\epsilon$? I'm guessing the answer is no, and if so, I'm also wondering what additional restrictions we might place on $f$ or $f'$ that would lead to a result along these lines, short of making $f'$ continuous.

For context, I'm interested in whether a finite selection of these delta balls can always cover the region, and under what conditions. I'm looking into alternative proofs of the Cauchy-Goursat integral theorem, which is why I can't use the continuity of the derivative.

This doesn't seem to be an easily searched topic, maybe because I'm lacking specific vocabulary. I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: if the complex derivative exists on a small open set, it is automatically continuos (and actually infinitely differentiable) there so I do not get the question

Comment: sorry @Conrad I should probably rephrase the question without mentioning complex derivatives... I got interested in this at a phase of theoretical development before the continuity of the derivative is proven

Comment: the point is that if $f$ is complex differentiable (and nothing else, no continuity on the derivative) on an open set, it is automatically analytic there, hence all its derivatives are as smooth as you want; if the function is just real differentiable, sure the question can be rephrased but then you have partial derivatives only (could use $\partial z, \partial \bar z$)

Comment: ok dropping complex differentiability was the wrong way to go, because of course it leads to partials and I don't think that will work for me -- I'll end up needing their continuity, which is what I'm trying to avoid. hopefully I've made it clear with my last edit. thanks!